# Transaction for getting surname of logged-in user

Tags: authentication, sap-basis

How can I identify who an SAP login belongs to?

For example, login: `C50521`, and I am looking for name, surname, of `C50521`

Please, provide transaction if exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `SU01` and enter SAP login there. On the first tab you should see First and Last names, if they are maintained and if they are real. And of course if you possess proper authorizations.

**UPDATE:** If one have no access to `SU01`, `SU10` (Mass editing of users) can be the option too.

Comment: If you don't have access to SU01, you may have access to SU01D which is a display only transaction.

Comment: I dont have access to SU01, I will try the second one and will let you know

Comment: @4est, SU10 can be an option too.

Comment: I don't have access to all SU*....I checked on other id (with admin rights) and it's run correclty, thank you !